# How can I know the path of the running script in Python?

Tags: python, path

My script.py creates a temporary file using a relative path.

When running it as:

```
python script.py
```

it works as expected.

But it doesn't work when you run it like:

```
python /path/to/script.py
```

The problem is that I don't know which path it will be running in. How can I get the absolute path to the script folder (the "/path/to") so the temporary file can be created in the same directory as the script?

What about the following?

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the great [Dive Into Python](http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/regression_path.html):

```
import sys, os

print 'sys.argv[0] =', sys.argv[0]             1
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])        2
print 'path =', pathname
print 'full path =', os.path.abspath(pathname)
```

Comment: What about os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(\_\_file__)) ?

Comment: As per other [great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1297407/1226722) which explains exactly why `__file__` is not what you're looking for: `__file__` is the path of the currently executing file (script or module). This is *accidentally* the same as the script if it is accessed from the script.

Comment: @gregoltsov  ```__file__```  does not work when you compile to .exe with pyinstaller

Answer (score 9):

The two current answers reflect the ambiguity of your question.

When you've run `python /path/to/script.py`, where do you want your tempfile?  In the current directory (`./tempfile.txt`) or in `/path/to/tempfile.txt`?

If the former, you can simply use the relative path (or, for weird and arcane purposes, get the absolute path equivalent to the current directory as @Desintegr suggests, with `os.getcwd`).

If the latter, you can learn exactly how the script was invoked with `sys.argv[0]`, as @Jonathan suggests, and manipulate that path with the functions in `os.path` (of course you can also apply those functions to what `os.getcwd` returns, if the former case applies), or work with `os.path.dirname(__file__)` and the like (the latter's necessary if you want this latter behavior also when the script is imported as a module, not just when it's run as a main script).

Comment: Thanks, I want the temp file in the same dir as the script.py

Comment: @Juanjo, then `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is probably best and the answer you've selected second-best (as it requires one more `import` -- of `sys` -- which using `__file__` avoids).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [os.getcwd()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getcwd) method to know the current working directory.

> Return a string representing the current working directory. 
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

You can use the [os.chdir(path)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) method to change the current working directory.

> Change the current working directory to path. 
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

Comment: This answers a completely different question than the one being asked.