# Python & Eclipse - Get curent filename error

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, filenames, os.path

I decided to start using Eclipse to code in python, but I am having problems getting the filename of the current script. To get the current filenam I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
os.path.basename(__file__)
```

My code works flawlessly when using the bash terminal or Geany, but with Eclipse Interactive Console I get:

```
 name '__file__' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

When I run my code using `python filename.py` it works perfectly, but when I try running it from the python or ipython consoles I get the same error

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint somewhere in your code and debug. Check `__file__` in the debug console and see if it works

Comment: Does other python code work when ran from the interactive console?

Comment: @jorgehumberto do any other magic variables work?

Comment: @jorgehumberto or are you using the standard python interpreter with eclipse?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget nope, nothing, it just terminates and I get nothing on the variable '__file__'

Comment: @Drew I installed PyDev as per http://www.vogella.com/articles/Python/article.html

Comment: @jorgehumberto hmm does it show the command that is being executed when you run it from the gui?

Comment: @Drew I tried `__main__` and I am getting the same problem. And the console shows me the command being executed.

Comment: @jorgehumberto Hmmm...do they do anything here (http://www.cs.rit.edu/~vcss242/Docs/SystemSetupInstructions2012.html) that you didn't do when you set it up?

Comment: @Drew The only difference I could find with what I did is that I am using python2.7 and not 3.x. I added python 3.3 to the config and still no luck

Comment: @jorgehumberto hmm, intriguing, what command does it show being executed when you try to run your program?

Comment: @Drew I updated my question, not sure if it helps

Comment: @Drew it shows `os.path.basename(__file__)`, which is the comment I am trying to run

Comment: @jorgehumberto is there a `python yourfilename` being executed I'm guessing?

Comment: @Drew no, in the console it does: `execfile(filename)`

Comment: @jorgehumberto Gotcha. Have you tried executing the file from the command line with that syntax? If so, do you get the same error?

Comment: @Drew if I run `python filename` it works with no issue, but if I go to the python console and run `execfile(filename)` I get the same error as above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38804/discussion-between-drew-and-jorgehumberto)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an alternative method that works with PyDev's interactive console from:

[How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python)

The solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import inspect
filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename.split('/')[-1]
```