# Trouble running using subprocess to call python script in command line

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a python script from another script using the following method:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['python script.py'])
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The files are both in the same directory. Help please.

Comment: Have you considered to put the code inside `script.py` inside functions and use `import script; value = script.some_function(a, b)` instead of running it as a subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `python` and `script.py` as separated items:

```
call(['python', 'script.py'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent script is run from a different directory then you need a way to find where the script is stored:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_call

script_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
check_call([sys.executable or 'python', os.path.join(script_dir, 'script.py')])
```

See also [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)