# Running commands/programs with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to the `subprocess` module in python.

The documentation provided this example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
b'Hello World!\n'
```

What I tried is:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["cd", "../tests", "ls"])
/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: ../tests: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cd', '../tests', 'ls']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I am confused because this is my file structure:

```
   /proj
      /cron
         test_scheduler.py
      /tests
         printy.py
         test1.py
         test2.py
         ...
```

These are my other attempts as well:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["cd", "../tests", "python", "printy.py"])
/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: ../tests: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cd', '../tests', 'python', 'printy.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1


>>> subprocess.check_output(["cd", "../tests;", "ls"])
/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: ../tests;: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cd', '../tests;', 'ls']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try to avoid `shell=True` if possible.**

In this case, you can certainly avoid. The problem you are facing is: `cd` is a shell builtin. Its not a command/program/utility that can be called from outside. You need to be within a shell for `cd` to work. What you can instead do is change your current directory. Execute the command. And then go back to your original directory.

You'll need to do something like the below:

```
pathBefore = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/path/to/your/directory")
subprocess.check_output(["ls"])
os.chdir(pathBefore) # get back to the path we were in before
```

---

**UPDATE**: [A better approach pointed out by @JFSebastian is to use the additional `cwd` argument to `check_output` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28508621/227884).

Comment: That is probably why I adopted to write Shell=True - as one of my first attempts was a cd. Now all pieces of the puzzle fall in place :)

Comment: If you are not doing anything with the shell, you are best away from using `shell=True`. It might seem like it makes life easy for you, but trust me, it might give you headaches in the long run.

Comment: True. My one time I used python was just when I needed some backup script while in a curious mood of trying some other language. So I have no deeper knowledge on best practices with python.

Comment: `/usr/bin/cd` (shown in the error  message) is not a shell builtin. You should [use `cwd` parameter instead of `os.chdir()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28508621/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks! I agree, `cwd` argument is a better choice. I will edit my answer. BTW, great observation about  `/usr/bin/cd`. It actually prompted me to read up a bit, and found out that [`cd` is provided both as a shell builtin as well as a regular program.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38819/20629). Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The relative path to the `tests` directory depends on where the script is being run from. I would suggest calling `subprocess.check_output(["pwd"])` to check where you are.

Also you can't combine two commands in the same call like in your attempt with `["cd", "../tests", "python", "printy.py"]`. You'll need to make two separate calls with `["cd", "../tests"]` and `["python", "printy.py"]` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear:

> /usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: ../tests: No such file or directory

that is you have successfully started `/usr/bin/cd` program that failed and printed the error message.

If you wanted to run `ls` command from `../tests` directory instead:

```
import os
import subprocess

cwd = os.path.join(get_script_dir(), '../tests')
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls'], cwd=cwd)
```

where [`get_script_dir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).

Note: do not use a relative path for the directory -- your script can be run from a different directory -- relative paths fail in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a argument here I think.
Here a snippet from the only python script I ever wrote:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from subprocess import call
...
call( "rm " + backupFolder + "*.bz2", shell=True )
```

Please note the `shell=True` in the end of that call.

Comment: This is not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess