# "no such file or directory" in python script calling other python script in debian linux

Tags: php, python, subprocess, call

Hi I've got the following written in a python script pythonscript1.py in linux debian in the directory /home/user/a/:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python" /home/user/b/phpcall.py"])
```

where the phpcall.py script contains:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["php", "/home/user/b/phpscript1.php"])
```

individually called from console all scripts function perfectly, but when I use the first script whilst the 2nd script calls/looks for a file in directory b, rather than a, It yields the following error:

```
"PHP warning: include_once(something.php): failed to open stream: no such file in /home/user/b/phpschript1.php on line 25
```

Now it is quite clear to me the problem is that it cannot reach out of it's original directory. But I don't know what command I should add to the first script to allow the 2nd script to look in folder b.

So far google results have suggested something with "include_path='include'" but I don't know how/where to incorporate the statement succesfully.

Any suggestions on the correct syntax would be appreciated!

Comment: change python's working dir to `/home/user/b` first? or change php's include call to `include('/absolute/path/to/something.php')` instead.

Comment: Thank you, the first one was obvious, I'm googling how to do that now, and I'm gonna try to incorporate the 2nd option if I do not succeed in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the code that directly called the php script from python within was:

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/user/b")
os.system("php /home/user/b/phpscript1.php")
```

.Thanks Marc B
& I love the dynamic approach Sebastian, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this program:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(
       [sys.executable, '/home/user/b/phpcall.py'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.communicate()
```

i think it's work. if not let know.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion Najeeb! It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `php` script works only if you start it from the directory with the python script then you could use `cwd` parameter to change the working directory for the subprocess:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["php", "/home/user/b/phpscript1.php"], cwd="/home/user/b")
```

I've added the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` so that you could run the script directly as `/path/to/phpcall.py` assuming it is executable (`chmod +x phpcall.py`).

Note: if you want to run the python script as `user` user then you could specify the path using `~`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from subprocess import check_call

script_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/b")
check_call(["php", os.path.join(script_dir, "phpscript1.php")], cwd=script_dir)
```

To avoid hardcoding the script directory, you could find it dynamically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from subprocess import check_call

script_dir = get_script_dir()
check_call(["php", os.path.join(script_dir, "phpscript1.php")], cwd=script_dir)
```

where [`get_script_dir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).