# Setting a working folder to where my script lives in Python

Tags: python, directory, filepath

I was looking for an easy way to set a working folder at the beginning of my script to avoid having to change it each time I run my script from another machine. Sorry if it is silly but I can't find an answer without having to dive deeply into the sea of weird functions - and I don't know how to swim.

I would use it to save all images to the same specific folder.

My take:

```
#import stuff
filepath=raw_input('Provide the working directory: ')
#do stuff
plt.savefig(filepath+'\\image.jpg', dpi=2000,bbox='tight')
```

**EDIT**
I have a number of files to save in one specific directory, the same where my script lives. But it is specified like this: `C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\N_Scripts` and it is on my own pc, but I oftentimes work on a different machine. How to preset the directory where all my images go to at the beginning of my script with something like `raw_input`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The error occurs before or during execution?

Comment: I didn't down-vote the question still my explanation for down vote would be `I can't find a quick and easy answer` not on your knowledge level.

Comment: @Don: it occurs right after having typed it.

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani I figure out you're using matplotlib. Can you provide all relevant parts of the script? (e.g. imports)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the idea is to get rid of having to retype a different directory each time I run my script from a different machine. How and where in the script would you use `os.path.join`? Before or after `plt.savefig`?

Comment: @Don These are my imports: `import numpy`, `from numpy import *`, `import networkx as nx`, `from networkx import *`, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `import csv`, `from collections import *`, `from __future__ import division`, `import os`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to save in one specific directory, the same where my script lives

To change the current working directory inside your Python script to a directory where your script lives:

```
import os

os.chdir(get_script_dir())
```

where [`get_script_dir()` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).

> But then, once you use os.chdir, how do I modify the argument of plt.savefig to make sure my images are saved where my script is?
>   Would it just be plt.savefig(os.chdir(get_script_dir())+'\image.jpg)?

Use `plt.savefig('image.jpg')`.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible to use something like `raw_input` to allow the user to pre-determine the dir where he/she wants the files to be saved...

Comment: But then, once you use `os.chdir`, how do I modify the argument of `plt.savefig` to make sure my images are saved where my script is? Would it just be `plt.savefig(os.chdir(get_script_dir())+'\\image.jpg)`?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani: you have asked *"where my script lives"*. If you want something different; it is a different question. Obviously, you *can* ask user if you want (you could use `raw_input()` on Python 2, to ask from the command line or you could use `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` to ask via GUI).