# Specify path to sibling folder in a non-absolute way

Tags: python

Let's say that I have a folder, `x`, containing the two folders `foo` and `bar`. Inside `foo` I have a Python script and inside `bar`, I have my data (let's say a couple of `.txt` files). Now, from within my script, I would like to access my data. I could simply use this command and call it a day:

```
fileList = glob.glob('/absolute/path/to/bar/*.txt')
```

However, using this method, my script would break if I moved my `x` folder.

What's the easiest way to specify the path in a relative manner that allows me to move around the parent folder, `x`, freely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`../` specifies your parent directory, so `../bar/*.txt`.

Like John Gordon said, this works assuming you're inside `x/foo/` and running the script from there.

If you're not executing the script from its own directory, you'll need to find out where your script currently is. This is not trivial. felipsmartins' solution of using `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is generally fine, but doesn't work in all cases. See e.g. here: [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python)

Comment: ... assuming the user is sitting inside the `foo` folder when they run the script.

Comment: This is the answer I thought you were looking for. Another approach would be to store the directories in a config file and use [ConfigParser][1]to read them in at run time.   [1]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: @MarcoTompitak Oh, no... My solution works well in all cases.

Comment: The link I provided highlights some problems with the `__file__` method. Granted, it works in most cases, I just wanted to add the caveat that in some scenarios it does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think `__file__` is a nice approach:

```
import glob
import os

# "x" folder
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))   
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(base_dir, 'bar', '*.txt'))
```

Working from top directory is a lot easier. Django and other frameworks [does](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py#L16) it too.
Also, it solves issues when invoking script from command line and from different locations.

Another approch is usging `os.chdir()`, changing working directory:

```
import glob
import os

# same that: cd /absolute path/for/x folder
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

files = glob.glob(os.path.join('bar', '*.txt'))
```

Zend Framework (PHP) [uses](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php#L10) the above approach in bootstrap file.

**Both solutions works very well for all cases.**

Comment: So the assumption with this answer is that the directories are always in the same position relative to the program file, it is just the base directory that moves. In that case, I like this idea.