# Making a directory for a file

Tags: python, windows, directory

I was making a exercise generator algorithm for my friend, but I stumbled across a problem. It is a python program, and I wanted to generate a folder in a directory that was above the program's location (like, the python file is in 'C:\Documents\foo' and the folder should be created in 'C:\Documents') so that it could then store the file the program created. Is there a way to do this or should I try something else?

Answer (score 2):

Use the path argument of the `os.mkdir()` [function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_mkdir.htm).

Getting the current script directory is not a built-in feature, but there are multiple hacks suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python).

Once you get the current script directory, you can build a path based off of that.

Comment: The os module worked! Thank you! (Also, to find the current directory, you can use os.getcwd)

Comment: @D4rkM4sterBR, I edited the answer to avoid confusing the script directory with the process current directory. You do not want `os.getcwd`. See the linked question.

Comment: I found out you can split the os.getcwd string into a list, reverse it, delete the last item (which would be the current folder), reverse it again, join it, and you will get the upper folder. It also works.

Comment: Well I'm not really for using `os.getcwd`. If you're doing that regardless, you can use `list.pop(0)` (where list is your list obtained by the original split) to remove the first item of the list.

Comment: @D4rkM4sterBR, you said "generate a folder in a directory that was above the program's location". `os.getcwd` is completely unrelated to this requirement. The current working directory can be *anything* depending on the working directory of the parent process (e.g. cmd.exe or explorer.exe) or a directory passed explicitly to [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425) as `lpCurrentDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with Python in a Windows environment, but this should be easily do-able. Here is a similar question that might be worth looking at: [How to check if a directory exists and create it if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary)

Looks like the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) might do what you are looking for.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("/my/directory/filename.txt")
try:
    if not path.parent.exists():
        path.parent.mkdir(parents=True)
except OSError:
    # handle error; you can also catch specific errors like
    # FileExistsError and so on.
```

Comment: I don't quite get it, but I'm going to look into it. I didn't even know this library existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to work on Win 7 with Python 2.7.8 as described:

```
import os.path

createDir = '\\'.join((os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)), 'Foo'))

if not os.path.exists(createDir):
    os.makedirs(createDir)
```