# Python Error: print subprocess.check_output - invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, casperjs

Working on a CasperJS tutorial and I'm getting an error with my syntax. Using Python 3.5.1.

File: scrape.py

```
import os
import subprocess

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
CASPER = '/projects/casperjs/bin/casperjs'
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'test.js')

params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT

print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
```

Error:

```
File "scrape.py", line 10
    print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

YouTube Video tutorial: [Learning to Scrape...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Acrx-AjCo8Q)

Comment: unrelated: 1- if `APP_ROOT` has spaces in it; the `check_output()` call may fail because `CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT` is not how the command line should be created. It seems, you don't need the shell here 2- if you want to display the output; you don't need to capture it: `check_call([CASPER, SCRIPT])`  3- minor: you could [use `get_script_dir()` instead of `__file__`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True)` is Python 2 syntax.  `print` is a keyword in Python 2 and a function in Python 3.  For the latter, you need to write:

```
print(subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True))
```

Comment: Thanks, I discovered the whole print became a function thing, but didn't get my parenthesis right.