# Importing Modules VSCode Python3

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Trying to run the following in VSCode:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = tabulate([["value1", "value2"]], ["column 1", "column 2"], tablefmt="grid")
print(table)
```

But I get this exception:

> Exception has occurred: ImportError
>   cannot import name 'tabulate'

My launch.json looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
```

I have tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module) but it did not work. I am not running in a virtualenv. And it is not a problem with tabulate because the same issue arises with other modules. Also, I know tabulate is properly installed because the code above compiles just fine when I run it in the WingPersonal IDE. Any ideas?