# Python ModuleNotFoundError when not in working directory; getcwd finds module

Tags: python, directory-structure

When I try to run a python file with `python3.6 src/main.py` (the working directory is one above `src`) there's this error when importing another module from path `src`:

```
from src import another_module
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

When I do

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```

I get what's expected:

> path/to/working/directory
>
> ['src']

The import works when I run the script with PyCharm, but I need to run it outside PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved** by creating another file `run.py` in the working directory that calls `src/main.py` and running `run.py` from the command line instead of `src/main.py`.

Comment: But it's weird that `print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))` finds the module and the import command doesn't.

Comment: how did you call `src/main.py` (in `run.py`)?

Comment: @nicolas `from src import main` then `main.main()`

Comment: And you don't have a file `__init__.py`?

Comment: @nicolas No, I don't.

Comment: IDK, nothing makes sense.

Comment: John was correct, python3 has an implicit `__init__.py` so it makes sense now. Your `run.py` works, but it seems to contain what you mentioned in your initial question, which failed with `ModuleNotFoundError` (i.e. `from scr import main`). So I am not completely sure what you tried.

Comment: After an hour of googling, a variation of this is the ONLY thing that solved my dreaded `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named` error

Answer (score 1):

When you run a python script on the command line, the script's directory (which may not be the same as your *shell current working directory*) is added to the path.

So, since `src/` is already in your path, you can just say `import another_module`.

Comment: Interesting, but then it doesn't work in PyCharm anymore (since the working directory is properly set on PyCharm; the working directory is *not* 'src'). Is there a way to make it work in both?

Answer (score 1):

To make `src` a package, make an empty file named `src/__init__.py`

Comment: `__init__.py` is not required in Python 3.

Comment: I still got the same error: 

`print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
print(os.listdir('src'))

from src import my_module

path/to/working/directory`



>['src']
>['__pycache__', 'my_module.py', '__init__.py']
>
>Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "src/main.py", line 12, in <module>
>    from src import time_functions as time
>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Comment: The doc for [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) shows how the directory structure should look like. And `__init__.py` is still required for python3.

Comment: @Raphael: where are you executing those python statements from? A file in your top directory?

Comment: My mistake; I overlooked that you were making `src` a _package_, and not just an _importable module_.

Comment: @JohnGordon: Regarding implicit `__init__.py` in python3, you are right according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3).

Answer (score -1):

In launch.json, add the following line to your deployment:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}
```

This seems to force Python to evaluate imports relative to the `${workingSpaceRoot}` folder; allowing you to use a fully qualified name: from *src* import ...

The default behavior is to evaluate namespaces relatively. So, your original statement: `from src import ...` is actually looking in `src/src/...`.

(Credit to @g4th who posted this solution on another StackOverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631996/4093278).)

Comment: This applies to what tricks `VSCode` does before run. Nobody asks for advice about VSCode here.