# unable to import the module that i have just installed in VS code(i am using Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have installed package playsound and this is my command and its response:

```
pip install playsound
```

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
> Collecting playsound
> Downloading playsound-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
> Installing collected packages: playsound
> Successfully installed playsound-1.2.2

But when I want to use this package I see error like this:

> python ./musicplay.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "./musicplay.py", line 1, in 
> from playsound import playsound
> ImportError: No module named playsound

Comment: You might restart VScode and try again. Do you use any environemnts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode import error for python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module)

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check `pip list` to check if the package is installed properly. Also, run `which python` to make sure that the virtual env where you have installed and where you are executing code is the same.

Also, try running your imports in the python terminal