# How to fix Error “unable to import pynput.keyboard”? even after downloading with pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keylogger

I downloaded the pynput on my mac(running Big Sur) with

```
pip install pynput
```

nd when I run the code, VSCode show the error:

`Unable to import 'pynput.keyboard'pylint(import-error)`

Here is my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "keylogs.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module/58147029#58147029) solve your problem.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved the link you sent is not helping

Comment: then make sure you installed your library in write environment

Comment: everything is perfect but still not working