# Python module import statement runs in PyCharm but not in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here's my file structure

```
test/
  -dir1
    -thing.py
  -dir2
    -__init__.py
    -thing2.py
```

I am using python 3.7 and windows 10.

In `thing.py`, I'm trying to import a function called `foo` from `thing2.py` and have it execute when I run `thing.py`. My code works perfectly in PyCharm when I press run. However, when I run `thing.py` from the terminal directly or through code runner in VSCode, I get the following error:

`from dir2.thing2 import foo`

ERROR: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir2`

Is the issue something to do with my PYTHONPATH or something else?

Comment: I'd compare the current working directory when running your script on both pycharm and on vs code.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [visual studio code - vscode import error for python module - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module) (the answers there are fine, but the OP is doing manuallies is.path modification?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described. And you could use the following methods to solve it:

1. Please add the following code at the beginning of the "`thing.py`" file, which adds the path of the currently opened file to the system path so that VSCode can find "`foo`" according to "`from dir2.thing2 import foo`":

> ```
> import os, sys 
> sys.path.append('./')
> ```

[image]

2. If you don't want to add code, you could add the following setting in "`launch.json`", which adds the path of the project when debugging the code:

> ```
>  "env": {
>                     "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
>                 }
> ```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, this solved my problem. Thanks!