# Import "dateutil" could not be resolved from source

Tags: python

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write a small script and part of it involves using `dateutil` to parse a string and see if a date exists. Very straight forward, but for some reason, `import dateutil` just doesn't work.

I've read around and I've tried every suggestion I've ran into

- Making sure that `pip -V` and `python -V` correspond with the correct version of Python (Pip is v.3.10 and Python is v.3.10.5)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling dateutil via `pip uninstall python-dateutil` and `pip install python-dateutil`. Tried both `pip install python-dateutil` AND `pip3 install python-dateutil` after I uninstalled and neither works.
- Doing all that AND restarting the IDE
- Double checked to see if `pip` was added to my PATH variable properly (it is; echo %PATH% shows the correct directories)

I'm not sure why this is happening or what else I can try to do to resolve it

Comment: Can you show pip logs?

Comment: Are you installing the module to the same virtualenv that you are using to run?

Comment: Can you show us the traceback?  You don't have a local file called "dateutil.py", do you?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? *What happens* when you try to `import dateutil`? If there is an error, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error traceback.

Comment: Just because `pip` uses the same numbered *version* of Python, doesn't mean it's using the same *installation*. This is one reason why `python -m pip` is recommended. That said, your IDE could use a different installation from the one that you get using `python` on the command line, too. People have all kinds of strange installation setups out there, and there's no way we can just guess what's on your system.

Comment: [Download](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/#files) the `.whl` file and install the module from that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error a couple of times the last months.
For me, the issue has been connected to the **Python interpreter** in use
*(I believe this is only an issue if you are using a virtual environment)*

The solution has been to replace the *venv interpreter* (recommended) with the *global interpreter* of the same version. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73583374/9761106) to a similar thread for instructions/screenshots