# VSCODE import error post vscode update 12-12-2023

Tags: python, import, module

For a year plus I have resolved the import error by adding

```
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~/sync/Coding/Templates"))
```

This folder holds a file called Template.py

```
import Template as T

T.func_whatever()
```

(where I have a bunch of functions that I use)

As of two days ago; I think the latest VSCode update, VSCode does not recognize a single function that was added to Template.py as of the UPDATE, but it does recognize all the prior functions in Template.

Needless to say this is bonkers. I have tried updating
settings.json and adding "env: whatever" from this answer

[vscode import error for python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you edit `Template.py`?  Are you sure you _saved_ the changes?

Comment: Are you running vs code from the same user account as before the update?