# os.path.abspath vs os.path.dirname

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

These are equal in string value, but are they truly equal? What is going on where?

```
import os

path_name1 = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path_name2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

print(path_name1)
print(path_name2)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3718657/674039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__), the value of `__file__` is a string, which is set when module was imported by a loader. From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader.load_module) you can see that the value of `__file__` is

> The path to where the module data is stored (not set for built-in modules).

Usually, the path is already the absolute path of the module. So, the line 4 of your code can be simplified to `path_name2 = os.path.dirname(__file__)`. Obviously, the line 3 of your code can be presented as `path_name1 = os.path.abspath(path_name2)` (let us ignore the order of execution for now).

The next thing is to see what does `dirname` do. In fact, you can view `dirname` as a wrapper of `os.path.split`, which splits a path into two parts: `(head, tail)`. `tail` is the last part of the given path and `head` is the rest of the given path. So, the `path_name2` is just the path of the directory containing the loaded file. Moreover, `path_name2` is a absolute path. Hence `os.path.abspath(path_name2)` is just the same with `path_name2`. So, `path_name1` is the same with `path_name2`.

Comment: Okay this makes sense, however how can line 4 be simplified to path_name2 = os.path.dirname(__file__).  That just seems to return a blank  output of <class 'str'> with a len of 0.  Though thanks to your answer I understand why os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath)) is what it is.

Comment: If you put the code into a file, say "test.py", and execute it with command "python3 test.py", you will find that the output of "os.path.dirname(__file__)" is blank. However, if you open an python interpreter, and use "import test", you will find the output is not blank.