# Accessing the filepath where I called python from

Tags: python

I would like to use the filepath of where I called Python from, but I have not found the solution for this yet (perhaps I'm bad at searching).

Example:

Contents of `foo.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

```
$ pwd
/Here
$ python3 folder1/foo.py
'/Here/folder1'
```

This is the result I currently get, but I would like to have access to '/Here'.

Comment: Try `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Save it to a variable

```
import os

pypath = os.getcwd()
```

In general the os module will be useful for these types of things and if you want to look at all the files in the current directory(path) then its `os.listdir(".")`, note the `"."` will equal `os.listdir()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `os.getcwd()` from os module. [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) contains list of paths in which python will search for the modules that you are importing