# Selenium - Error

Tags: python, selenium

This is my current code in python 2.7:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver.exe')

# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("Cheese!")

# submit the form (although google automatically searches now without submitting)
inputElement.submit()

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

try:
    # we have to wait for the page to refresh, the last thing that seems to be updated is the title
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("cheese!"))

    # You should see "cheese! - Google Search"
print driver.title

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Here is my error I'm recieving:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\test55.py", line 7, in 
>           driver = webdriver.Firefox('geckodriver.exe')
>         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 134, in **init**
>       firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
>         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 78, in **init**
>       ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
>         File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 171, in copytree
>       names = os.listdir(src)
>       WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'geckodriver.exe/*.*'

I want the browser driver to be defined from the same folder as the program not from the PATH.

Any help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)