# python module not found via systemd, but works manually

Tags: python-3.x, request, debian, systemd

I have a code in python that I use

```
import requests
```

It´s works if I run the code on command line.

But when I put in systemd It didn't work.

In log I see error:

```
Aug  2 15:08:19 beaglebone python3[2140]:     import requests
Aug  2 15:08:19 beaglebone python3[2140]: ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

I´m using debian in BeagleBone

Comment: Are you sure they are using the same Python installation?

Comment: I think so 

In systemd I have: ** ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/debian/Sincronismo/EventHub.py **
(didn´t work)

If I put  ** /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/debian/EventHub.py ** in console, works

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a variation of the FAQ [Why do things behave differently under systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645).

This may have to do with the current working directory or environment variables that  provide Python library paths.

At top of your python code before your `import` line, immediately dump out the current working directory and all environment variables. Review the differences under systemd vs manual use.

I think you'll find the issue there. For example, if `requests` was found relative to your current working directory and `systemd` is using a different directory.

See the answer to above linked FAQ for more possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just starting with Linux.
I understood and think that the problem is with environment variables, but I´m confuse with the FAQ.

How can I "At top of your python code before your import line, immediately dump out the current working directory and all environment variables"?

Comment: See the answers for [finding the current directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory) and [printing the environment from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-do-i-access-environment-variables-from-python).  Handle those tasks as the first lines in your script.