# Nicest way to find current directory of file in python

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm looking for a replacement of

```
import os
package_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
file_path = os.path.join(package_dir,'foo.csv')
```

My working path isn’t the path of the file. So when I want to load a file, I need a way to generate the relative path compared to my working directory.

I want to update to pathlib (or whatever else is out there). But what is the nicest way to do the same?

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/44188489, but I don't think this solution looks better than my current way.

#### Remark:

It's not a duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory), since I explicitly asked about the nicest way. Most of the solutions in the other post don't look nice, or are already mentioned in the my question. The solution

```
Path(__file__).with_name("foo.csv")
```

given here is much better than the solutions given in the other question, since it's easy to understand, and a really pythonic way to solve it. If this question was a dublicate, on the other post an equally good answer would exist.

Comment: your first line looks perfectly fine to me. i *think* you don't need the os.path.abspath portion of it. As for pathlib, it comes into play once you have a path. its just a smarter way to deal with file paths. so it makes the 2nd line easier to write, but doesnt really do much for the first.

Comment: Why do you want to change?  What does your current solution do poorly?

Comment: The current version with os. is relative old. Pathlib was invented to replace most of the os. functionality.
That's why I'm looking for a new way to do the same with Pathlib. Maybe there is even a solution that is more comfortable, than the current solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking to do the same with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), it could look like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

package_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
file_path = package_dir.joinpath("foo.csv")
```

Unless you're changing current working directory, you may not really need/want to use `.absolute()`.

If you actually do not need to know what `package_dir` would be, you can also just get the `file_path` directly:

```
file_path = Path(__file__).with_name("foo.csv").absolute()
```

Which gives you new `Path` replacing the file name.

Comment: awesome :) This solution looks really clean and easy to understand.

Comment: I gotta admit, I really do like `pathlib` and I think it does allow for the whole files handling to be significantly cleaned up.

Comment: I had a problem with your one line solution and subfolders. I used this instead: ``Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("output/foo.csv")``

Comment: @subjord Could you perhaps be a little more specific about nature of the problem? We could try to find a solution and/or improve the answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried to use  Path(__file__).with_name("../folder/foo.csv") which leads to an error message.

Comment: Error message being? `.with_name()` does not seem to be anything that appeared later in the game. `__file__` would not work in an interactive python session as it's not defined. Hence my curiosity if there some other pitfall missed that should have been mentioned / documented.

Comment: If in the string in the brackets of `.with_name("")` contains a backslash, I get the following error message: ``raise ValueError("Invalid name %r" % (name))``

Comment: I'm referring to the handy one line solution `file_path = Path(__file__).with_name("foo.csv")`

Comment: I see. Yes, `with_name()` replaces the name portion, i.e. same path with a different filename. So, this method cannot be used if `name` passed is actually not just a pathname, but a (relative) path with directory bit in it. I.e. with `\ ` for `WindowPath` or `/` for `PosixPath`.