# I need to run a Python script by double clicking on it, but it only works in a particular folder

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I just wrote a Python script in PyCharm that automates a configuration process, based on some input files. When I run it in PyCharm, it takes those files from the same folder as the script and delivers an outcome based on the running of the script. The problem is that I need to give this script to other people who don't know programming at all and once they install Python, they should be able to just download the script that I am giving them, put all the needed input files in the same folder and then double click on the script to receive the outcome. If I double click on the script in the folder where I have the PyCharm project, double-clicking will give me the output file, working perfectly. If I move the script in another folder (along with the input files), double clicking will not work. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: Look at `__file__`

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist, thank you very much for your reply. As I mentioned, I am new to Python. Could you be so kind to give more details regarding this? Thank you. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the full path to the directory a Python file is contained in, write this in that file:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Then prepend `dir_path` to every file call you make.

Source: [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory?answertab=votes#tab-top)