# Jinja2 is not getting the template "No template file present: default.j2 "

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I created two file: one, main.py and the other, default.j2. When I run cmd from the folder "code" where both are located (main.py and default.j2,) it works fine, but I try to automate the script on Windows Task Scheduler, it displays "No template file present: default.j2" even though the template exists in the path/folder.

Below is the code I use to check to whether the path is found or not.

```
def render_template(template, **kwargs):
# check if template exists
if not os.path.exists(template):
    print('No template file present: %s' % template)
    sys.exit()

import jinja2
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
templ = templateEnv.get_template(template)

return templ.render(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://serverfault.com/questions/609651/what-is-the-default-working-directory-for-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-2008-r2) notes that Windows Task Scheduler runs from `c:\%WINDIR%\System32`. So if you are just using the file name for the file with Task Scheduler, it will look for `c:\%WINDIR%\System32\default.j2` instead of `(code)\default.j2`.

You can use

```
import os
os.chdir(code_dir)

(run your code)
```

Or you can try suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory) in case `main.py`'s location may change in the future, or you have other files like this in other directories. Thus one option would be:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Another option would be:

```
template = os.path.join(os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "default.j2")
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification. this has helped me :)

Comment: @hanan Glad I could help! I ran into the same problem several times w/Taskscheduler & likely will again--it's easy to forget the starting directory isn't the script file's directory. I don't know how familiar you are with python, but I highly recommend reading the OS documentation highly. I had a bunch of "Oh! I can do THAT?!" moments. It's helped with so much simple file/directory manipulation. The pathlib module is a bit more complex.