# Run chromedriver from current python folder that I have my project

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting the chromedriver.exe from a path from my pc:

```
executable_path='C:\programs\chromedriver.exe'
```

Is there a way to get it from the current source direcotry for my python project which is called 'SRC'
Basically can it be done using a relative path not an absolute one, so when i move the whole project (SRC folder) to another PC to be able to run the same webdriver?

Comment: did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your directory tree is something like that:

```
SRC
│   script.py
│   chromedriver.exe
```

In your `script.py`, you can:

```
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
executable_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Yup, did the trick, if you want, can u give me an example if the proect struct was abit more nested, like `dir1/dir2/SRC` ?

Comment: @michael It would still work, as long as `chromedriver.exe` is next to your script.

Comment: @michael If you want to give me a specific case where the files are located in separate locations, I can give a bit different example

Answer (score 0):

Use Webdriver manager here https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/ no need to worry about maintaining required chromedriver.exe file in the path. This will download the required driver specified in the code.