# Python script not running in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have a simple python script that when I run it via command line it'll run. I also created a batch file to run the python script as well. When I double click that it'll run just fine. I can't get either the python script or the batch file containing the python script to run in Windows Task Scheduler and get and error see below. I just want to be able to run the Python script or batch file via task scheduler. I've tried multiple things from other qustions on here about putting the full path in the arguments and start in locations, and still get the same results.

This is my batch file code that works when double clicking the file just fine but won't run in task scheduler: `"C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\brant.evans\SQ Back Office-COR - General\PCMS_Part_Comments\Current_CSV_Output\PCMS_Parts_CSV_to_Excel.py" pause`

Here is the error I get when running it via task scheduler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\SQ Back Office-COR - General\PCMS_Part_Comments\Current_CSV_Output\PCMS_Parts_CSV_to_Excel.py", line 7, in <module>
    df_new = pd.read_csv('Current_PCMS_Parts.csv')
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 814, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1045, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1862, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1357, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\brant.evans\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 639, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Current_PCMS_Parts.csv'
```

I just want to be able to either use the python script directly or the batch file that has the python script in it via Windows Task Scheduler so I can schedule it to run. I know that both work if I manually run them in the command prompt or just double clicking the batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you properly determine the current script directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution that solved this issue. Inside of the batch file I put the following:

In the batch file insert after first line being usually @echo off the lines:

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
The batch file should additionally contain as last two line executed before exiting batch file processing the two lines:

popd
endlocal