# os.getcwd() can't find current working directory

Tags: python

Whenever I try to get current working directory in `python` on windows with `os.getcwd()` it shows only the root directory.

for example this directory structure:

```
root\
ㄴbase\
ㄴㄴfile\
ㄴㄴㄴfile.py\
```

I use

```
# files.py
os.getcwd()
```

output will be:

```
\---> c:/root\
```

I want to get `c:/root/file`

any idea?
thanks in advance

+
actually os.getcwd() finds the 'root:\base\' at some point. but in other cases it doesn't find. so I wanted to know the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory)

Comment: if you start script or program in `C:/root` then it is your `current working directory` and it doesn't matter that `file.py` is in different place. `current working directory` doesn't mean `script folder` or `project folder`

Comment: @furas no I'm running the file in ```C://root//base```

Comment: if `os.getcwd()` shows only `c:/root` then you run code in `c:/root`, not in `c:/root/base`. You can change directory before you run code `cd c:/root/base ; python script.py`, or you can change it after running `os.chdir("c:/root/base")`

Comment: "Whenever I try to get current working directory in python on windows with os.getcwd() it shows only the root directory." - yes, because **that actually is** the current working directory. The thing that you want to get **is not**.

Answer (score 1):

Current working directory isn't the path of the script, it's where you are running the script from.

And apparently, you're running your script from `c:/root/` directory. If you want the directory of the script use this to get the script path

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
script_path = abspath(dirname(__file__))
```

or run the script from `c:/root/base/file` to get the path with `getcwd()`.

Comment: yeah I added something and I of course run the file in that location(c:/base/). but still in some cases it doesn't find. Also, I know the other approach to find where the script is.