# No such file or directory: 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'

Tags: python, gensim

I have this code :

```
import gensim
filename = 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)
```

and this is my folder organization thing :
[image of my folder tree that shows that the .bin file is in the same directory as the file calling it, the file being ai_functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGd27.png)

But sadly I'm not sure why I'm having an error saying that it can't find it. Btw I checked, I am sure the file is not corrupted. Any thoughts?

Full traceback :

```
  File "/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serv import app
  File "/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/serv/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from serv import routes
  File "/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/serv/routes.py", line 7, in <module>
    from serv.ai_functions import checkplagiarism
  File "/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/serv/ai_functions.py", line 31, in <module>
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1629, in load_word2vec_format
    return _load_word2vec_format(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1955, in _load_word2vec_format
    with utils.open(fname, 'rb') as fin:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 188, in open
    fobj = _shortcut_open(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 361, in _shortcut_open
    return _builtin_open(local_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
```

Comment: You should ideally include the full error message in your question, including any lines of traceback. How are you executing your `ai_functions.py` file?

Comment: I updated the question and added the traceback!

Comment: So I imported a function (check plagiarism) from the `ai_functions.py` file and i'm importing it to the routes.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'current working directory' that the Python process will consider active, and thus will use as the expected location for your plain relative filename `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin`, will depend on how you launched Flask.

You could print out the directory to be sure – see some ways at [How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory) – but I suspect it may just be the `/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/` directory.

If so, you could relatively-reference your file with the path relative to the above directory...

```
serv/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

...or you could use a full 'absolute' path...

```
/Users/Ile-Maurice/Desktop/Flask/flaskapp/serv/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

...or you could move the file up to its parent directory, so that it is alonside your Flask `run.py`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that was how it worked, I initially run the file run.py but I thought that the working directory would then be serv since run.py would run __init__.py. Thanks so much though!