# How to make web browser.open() work on MacOS

Tags: python, windows, macos, folium

I'm making a folium map tool in Python and need to make and executable for Windows, but I need a version for macOS also (Probably will convert to `.app`).

My code works fine on windows but **`webbrowser.open()` does not work on macOS.** Any ideas on how I can work around this?

Here's an example of code for a folium map:

```
import folium
import webbrowser

map = folium.Map(
    location=[39.82, -100],
    zoom_start=4)

folium.Marker(location=[39.82, -100]).add_to(map)

# Save map as html file and open in default web browser
map.save("Map.html")
webbrowser.open("Map.html")
```

Comment: What is your default browser? I recall seeing a bug that certain browsers don't work.

Comment: I've tried on Firefox, Safari and Chrome

Comment: I don't think you can just open a file like this. You'd need to use `file:///path/to/file.html` . Also as a [mcve], the folium code doesn't seem relevant

Comment: Why the Windows tag if the question is about Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a bit to figure out so here is the answer for anyone in the future who needs it:

```
import folium
import webbrowser
import os


map = folium.Map(
    location=[39.82, -100],
    zoom_start=4)

folium.Marker(location=[39.82, -100]).add_to(map)

filename = 'Map.html'
map.save(filename)

filepath = os.getcwd()
file_uri = 'file:///' + filepath + '/' filename
webbrowser.open_new_tab(file_uri)
```

Comment: I'd feel safer using the full file path for all operations...

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory