# How to Get the Path of the executing frozen script

Tags: python, windows, path, argv

If you are running a frozen python script (frozen using py2exe) from a directory and drive different from where the script is present, what is the best way to determine the path of the executing script?

Few solutions I have tried

```
inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
```

**Problem: Does not return the full path. It only returns the script name.**

```
os.path.abspath( __file__ )
```

**Problem: Doesn't work on Windows**

```
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

**Problem: Returns empty string.**

```
os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(way3))
```

**Will not work if the drive is different from the pwd**

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

**Will not work if the drive is different from the pwd**

Here is a minimal not-working example

```
D:\>path
PATH=c:\Python27\;c:\Users\abhibhat\Desktop\ToBeRemoved\spam\dist\;c:\gnuwin32\bin

D:\>cat c:\Users\abhibhat\Desktop\ToBeRemoved\spam\eggs.py
import os, inspect, sys
def way1():
    return os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

def way2():
    return inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())

def way3():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

def way4():
    try:
        return os.path.abspath( __file__ )
    except NameError:
        return "Not Found"
def way5():
    return os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(way3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Path to this script is",way1()
    print "Path to this script is",way2()
    print "Path to this script is",way3()
    print "Path to this script is",way4()
    print "Path to this script is",way5()

D:\>eggs
Path to this script is
Path to this script is eggs.py
Path to this script is D:\
Path to this script is Not Found
```

**Related Questions:**

- [How to know the path of the running script in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259503/how-to-know-the-path-of-the-running-script-in-python)
- [How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executin)
- [python, path of script [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595305/python-path-of-script)

**Note**

@Fenikso's solution will work if the script resides on the same drive where you are executing but when its on a different drive, it will not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach which works with cxFreeze when running from another drive even using PATH:

```
import sys

if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    print(sys.executable)
else:
    print(sys.argv[0])
```

From Python:

```
H:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\pwdme.py
```

From command line:

```
D:\>h:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\dist\pwdme.exe
h:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\dist\pwdme.exe
```

Using PATH:

```
D:\>pwdme.exe
h:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\dist\pwdme.exe
```

Comment: @Fenikso: This works perfectly. Before posting this question I have seen few references to the same problem in SO, but none of the answers is not correct per se'.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, code that acts differently depending from absolute paths is not a good solution.
It will be probably better a relative path solution. Use dirname to know the relative directory and os.sep for cross platform compatibility.

```
if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    full_real_path = os.path.realpath(sys.executable)
else:
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
    full_real_path = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])
```

the frozen attribute is python standard.

Take a look also at Esky : 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
```

That is what I use with cx_Freeze to get the directory from where the .exe is really running.

Comment: This will not work if the script is present in a different drive

Comment: @Abhijit - Sorry, I do not understand. This is fundamental part of all my frozen scripts and it never failed. Can you describe an example when this fails?

Comment: I have updated the example to include this scenario. If the drive is different, it just returns the drive name from where you are running.

Comment: @Abhijit - Hmmm. Actually that is the use of PATH what changes the behavior. And the way 2 is actually kind of working for me with cxFreeze.

Comment: Can you please amplify as to what do you mean by `And the way 2 is actually kind of working for me`. Are you saying that this will work even if the drive is different?

Comment: I made a mistake. It returns `h:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\pwdme.py` instead of `h:\Python\Examples\cxfreeze\dist\pwdme.exe`. Note the directory.