# Running a packaged Python program in Ubuntu

Tags: python, wxpython, cx-freeze, dpkg

I have written a python program and `cx_freeze` it so that it can be moved to other Linux machine to execute, everything went fine, except the following

After freezing all my python code, I then `dpkg build` it and marked */usr/bin/myProgram* as my installation directory, everything went fine, I can build and install the program to the designated directory but I can only change the directory and `./myProgram` to start my program, if I do not do so, I will be told the error of missing my *settings.xml* which is an external file sitting beside my main program which also resides in */usr/bin/myProgram*.

I want to make a desktop shortcut, and I assume full path is needed to execute the program without changing the directory to my program's directory first, is there anything I can do to make this happen?

Message shows that I am missing a *setting.xml* file when I use full path to run the program, but when I first change to that directory and `./myProgram`, it works fine

[image]

Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Also you can detect proper location of your executable which is independent of where and how it was ran from. Then you can append your file location to the executable directory path. So you do not load your file as `settings.xml` but `os.path.join(application_root_dir, "settings.xml")`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293808/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-executing-frozen-script/10294435#10294435 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to create a simple script to `cd` to the directory and run the executable with `./myProgram`, and then call that script with full path with desktop launcher.

Another way:
There's a `Path` key available in desktop launcher. You can set it like:

```
Path=working_directory_path
```

in the `.desktop` file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, indeed I have already used this method, but I assume we should have a better solution?

Comment: @user2499325 You can set working directory in .desktop file with `Path`

Comment: Thanks for the Path attribute, I got it done now!! I am just thinking that maybe there are something I can do in the cx_freeze process, maybe I do something wrong there...