# how can i get the executable's current directory in py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I use this bit of code in my script to pinpoint, in a cross-platform way, where exactly it's being run from:

```
SCRIPT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Pretty simple. I then go on to use `SCRIPT_ROOT` in other areas of my script to make sure everything is properly relative. My problem occurs when I run it through py2exe, because the generated executable doesn't set `__file__`, therefore my script breaks. Does anyone know how to fix or work around this?

Comment: There is an older duplicated question but with less answers: [Determining application path in a Python EXE generated by pyInstaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744)

Answer (score 27):

Here is the [py2exe documentation reference](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment) and here are the relevant items:

- `sys.executable` is set to the full pathname of the exe-file.
- The first item in `sys.argv` is the full pathname of the executable, the rest are the command line arguments.
- `sys.frozen` only exists in the executable. It is set to "console_exe" for a console executable, to "windows_exe" for a console-less gui executable, and to "dll" for a inprocess dll server.
- `__file__` is not defined (you might want to use sys.argv[0] instead)

It is not apparent from those docs whether "the exe-file" and "the executable" are the same thing, and thus whether `sys.executable` and `sys.argv[0]` are the same thing. Looking at code that worked for both script.py and py2exe_executable.exe last time I had to do this, I find something like:

```
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    basis = sys.executable
else:
    basis = sys.argv[0]
required_folder = os.path.split(basis)[0]
```

As I say that worked, but I don't recall why I thought that was necessary instead of just using `sys.argv[0]`.

Using only `basis` was adequate for the job in hand (read files in that directory). For a more permanent record, split something like `os.path.realpath(basis)`.

**Update** Actually did a test; beats guesswork and armchair pontification :-)

**Summary: Ignore sys.frozen, ignore sys.executable, go with sys.argv[0] unconditionally.**

Evidence:

=== foo.py ===

```
# coding: ascii
import sys, os.path
print 'sys has frozen:', hasattr(sys, 'frozen')
print 'using sys.executable:', repr(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.executable)))
print 'using sys.argv[0]:',    repr(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]   )))
```

=== setup.py ===

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['foo.py'])
```

=== results ===

```
C:\junk\so\py2exe>\python26\python foo.py
sys has frozen: False
using sys.executable: 'C:\\python26'
using sys.argv[0]: 'C:\\junk\\so\\py2exe' # where foo.py lives

C:\junk\so\py2exe>dist\foo
sys has frozen: True
using sys.executable: 'C:\\junk\\so\\py2exe\\dist'
using sys.argv[0]: 'C:\\junk\\so\\py2exe\\dist' # where foo.exe lives
```

Comment: I believe that sys.executable usually points to the python interpreter itself, which is what you want under py2exe, but not otherwise.

Comment: @prestomation: What is "the Python interpreter itself" in the py2exe case? What do you mean by "but not otherwise"?

Comment: "otherwise" is when you are running an interpreted file, which is most environments. In the py2exe case, I would imagine the interpreter is your py2exe, because it's included. It looks like your most recent edit confirms that.

Comment: What happens if you put the executable into a directory on the search path (PATH env. variable)? I find that `sys.argv[0]` does not have a directory component in this case.

Comment: @Ber yes I think that sys.argv[0] will capture the current working directory and may not be what you want...

Answer (score 9):

Py2exe does not define `__file__`: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment

The OP requested a py2exe friendly version of:

```
SCRIPT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

The best answer is to determine if python is frozen in an exe, py2exe has documentation on this:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/HowToDetermineIfRunningFromExe

```
import imp, os, sys

def main_is_frozen():
   return (hasattr(sys, "frozen") or # new py2exe
           hasattr(sys, "importers") # old py2exe
           or imp.is_frozen("__main__")) # tools/freeze

def get_main_dir():
   if main_is_frozen():
       return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
   return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

SCRIPT_ROOT = get_main_dir()
```

Since, the python is [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), here's an [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) version ...

```
try:
   if sys.frozen or sys.importers:
      SCRIPT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
except AttributeError:
   SCRIPT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Cheers!

Comment: @Ber you're right ... I should have read more carefully. Better?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what the question asked for. Thanks for great solution.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import os
import sys
os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

Comment: In my experience, using `sys.argv [0]` does not have a path to it when the program is found via the PATH variable.

Comment: @Ber, ...however, `py2exe` is a special case, and does set that to a fully qualified value in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv[0]` is a reliable way to get the path, as it will give the same result irrespective of being run as a script or exe
. To get the directory `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`

[image: comparison between file and exe]