# Py2Exe Location

Tags: python, windows, path, py2exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i get the executable's current directory in py2exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292703/how-can-i-get-the-executables-current-directory-in-py2exe)

Is there a way to get the path to the executable file currently running with py2exe? For example if I had an executable generated with py2exe stored in C:\Users\Desktop\John\myapp.exe, how can I get this path from within myapp.exe in Python in Wondows?

Thank you for any help in advance - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

py2exe sets `sys.executable` to the full pathname of the executable. `sys.argv[0]` should also give this path. See [Py2exeEnvironment](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeEnvironment) for the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The path to your `.exe` file should be stored in `sys.executable`.

The py2exe.org wiki [WhereAmI](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI) page has some useful examples that you may find helpful as well.

Interestingly, [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292703/how-can-i-get-the-executables-current-directory-in-py2exe/2293106#2293106) to [a similar question from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292703/how-can-i-get-the-executables-current-directory-in-py2exe) advocates using `sys.argv[0]` instead of `sys.executable`.  Either one should work fine from within py2exe.  I've always used `sys.executable` if `sys.frozen` was set, and never had any issues, but there shouldn't be any harm in using `sys.argv[0]` instead, either.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following:

```
def get_app_info():
  # determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
  application = {'path': './', 'dir': './', 'start': None}

  if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    application['path']   = sys.executable
    application['dir']    = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
  else:
    application['path']   = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[:1][0])
    application['dir']    = sys.path[0]
  return application
```