# How to run an EXE file using Standalone python script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, exe

i'm trying to run an exe file (say foo.exe) using python script exported to exe (say boo.exe) using py2exe, it always give the below error as can't find the specified file, but i'm pretty sure the foo.exe is exist and on same directory  with boo.exe, the code works fine before exporting the script into exe !

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\foo.exe'
```

the code is

```
os.startfile("foo.exe")
```

is it somekind of bug or limitation  [like this one](https://bugs.python.org/issue17023)

Comment: have you tried different commands to run executable file? for example, `os.popen('foo.exe')`?

Comment: Do you have your `exe` present under `Desktop`? Or is it your `cwd`?

Comment: Don't depend on the working directory to find files relative to your script or executable. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2292703.

Comment: @eryksun i tried to hardcode the absoulte path of the foo.exe file but it doesn't work either ! , for example i tried                                                            os.startfile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\foo.exe") with no sucess

Comment: @Andersson, yes i did and subprocess doesn't work as well

Comment: @shaktimaan both files are on the desktop

Comment: one more point to add, the boo.exe is running on a different windows machine where python is not installed

Comment: @client eastwood No my question was that whether your current working directory is `Desktop` too? When you run `os.startfile()` it looks for that `exe` in `os.getcwd()` and all the locations in `Environment Path` variable.

Comment: @shaktimaan yes i got your point, but as i said i've explicitly used the absolute path like os.startfile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\foo.exe")   ,,, i also tried to change the current working directory using CWD = os.getcwd()  then os.chdir(CWD) but neither did work !