# Python os.list_dir stopping one level short

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, executable

so I am trying to make an executable for one of my python programs. I need to have access to the files in the folder that my executable is located. Because this file might get moved around, I am using `import os; current_dir = os.getcwd()`.

When I run the program through terminal with `python filename.py` and I `print current_dir`, I get `/Users/User/Desktop/Executable/`.

When I run the executable by opening the .py with terminal through Finder (I am on OS X), and the `current_dir` is printed, I get `/Users/User`. Notice, this does not have the other 2 levels that I need, namely `Desktop/Executable`. Why might this happen?

Remark: This is just a one off, quick executable that isn't meant to be used for a long time, but is necessary, so making the .py executable serves our purpose. This was done by `chmod +x filename.py`.

The answer, which can be found following the comments of the chosen answer to this question is:

```
import os
import sys
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
     basis = sys.executable
else:
     basis = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: because your working directories are different, pass the full path to the directory

Comment: https://github.com/glue-viz/glue-bot/issues/2   This issue might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the appropriate file, it will return the path of the executable, or the path of the script.

```
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    basis = sys.executable
else:
    basis = sys.argv[0]
```

if this doesnt work for you try  chaning the else: section to

`os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))`

edit: obviously: `import sys`

Executables will add a frozen attribute, check for that attribute before checking the working directory. frozen applications will probably run against python.exe which will resolve your working directory differently

Comment: Even with this, and with changing the `else`, I am still getting the same behavior. Hmm. I'll keep playing with this. Thank you. I will say that the command that is run by Terminal when I open the .py with terminal is `/Users/User/Desktop/Executable/filename.py ; exit;`. I don't know if that is useful or not.

Comment: Is that where the python file actually exists? than isnt that correct?

Comment: The .py file exists at `/Users/User/Desktop/Executable/filename.py`.

Comment: and running the executable is still giving you the wrong path?

Comment: Correct. Running it with `python filename.py` inside of terminal gets me the current path, but using the .py as an executable currently does not give me the correct path.

Comment: hmm, maybe this thread can help out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292703/how-can-i-get-the-executables-current-directory-in-py2exe

Comment: That did help, I believe I will be able to figure this out, thanks to you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I got the answer. One of the dudes in my lab helped me out. The answer was to do, in the `else`, `basis = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory is not necessarily the same directory where the file actually resides.  To get the path of the actual file, you could use:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for os.getcwd() says: Return a string representing the current working directory. Current working directory may not be where the python script is located.
You should check the documentation for a function that will give you the directory of the script, not the working directory, which may be different.