# How to find the filename of a script being run when it is executed from a symlink on linux

Tags: python, linux, filenames, symlink

If I have a python script that is executed via a symlink,  is there a way that I can find the path to the script rather than the symlink?  I've tried using the methods suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296501/python-find-path-to-file-being-run) question, but they always return the path to the symlink, not the script.

For example, when this is saved as my "/usr/home/philboltt/scripts/test.py" :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print sys.argv[0]
print __file__
```

and I then create this symlink

```
ln -s /usr/home/philboltt/scripts/test.py /usr/home/philboltt/test
```

and execute the script using

```
/usr/home/philboltt/test
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/home/philboltt/test
/usr/home/philboltt/test
```

Thanks!
Phil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `os.path.realpath()` function.

Answer (score 3):

[`os.readlink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.readlink) will resolve a symlink, and [`os.path.islink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) will tell you if it's a symlink in the first place.

Comment: Cool, but how do you check if something is a symlink? What will os.readlink() return if pointed to a non-link? I suppose this is not hard to test.

Comment: What about race conditions? It could get replaced by a symlink after you check but before you call readlink...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to check if the file is a symlink, and if so, get where it is linked to.  For example...

```
try:
    print os.readlink(__file__)
except:
    print "File is not a symlink"
```

Comment: os.path.realpath(__file__) is the better answer your question actually