# How do I get the full path of the current file's directory?

Tags: python, directory

How do I get the current file's directory path?
I tried:

```
>>> os.path.abspath(__file__)
'C:\\python27\\test.py'
```

But I want:

```
'C:\\python27\\'
```

Comment: `__file__` is not defined when you run python as an interactive shell. The first piece of code in your question looks like it's from an interactive shell, but would actually produce a `NameError`, at least on python 2.7.3, but others too I guess.

Comment: Why. is. this. so. hard. There are like a dozen SO threads on this topic. Python: "Simple is better than complex...There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: os.path.split(file_path)[0]

Comment: @eric it isn't hard, and the existence of multiple questions isn't evidence of something being hard - it's evidence of people not doing good research, of question titles being suboptimal for SEO, and/or of people failing to close duplicates that should be closed.

Comment: print(os.getcwd())

Answer (score 2713, accepted):

The special variable [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do) contains the path to the current file. From that we can get the directory using either [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) module.

### Python 3

For the directory of the script being run:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

For the current working directory:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path().resolve()
```

### Python 2 and 3

For the directory of the script being run:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If you mean the current working directory:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

Note that before and after `file` is two underscores, not just one.

Also note that if you are running interactively or have loaded code from something other than a file (eg: a database or online resource), `__file__` may not be set since there is no notion of "current file". The above answer assumes the most common scenario of running a python script that is in a file.

### References

1. [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) in the python documentation.
2. [os.path - Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html), [os.path - Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)
3. [os.getcwd - Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.getcwd), [os.getcwd - Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)
4. [what does the __file__ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Comment: abspath() is mandatory if you do not want to discover weird behaviours on windows, where dirname(__file__) may return an empty string!

Comment: should be os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.__file__))?

Comment: @drbailey: no. What makes you think that it should?

Comment: @BryanOakley __file__ is not defined, though perhaps this is unique to ActivePython installs?

Comment: @DrBailey: no, there's nothing special about ActivePython. `__file__` (note that it's two underscores on either side of the word) is a standard part of python. It's not available in C-based modules, for example, but it should always be available in a python script.

Comment: I would recommend using realpath instead of abspath to resolve a possible symbolic link.

Comment: In Windows Powershell you may need quotation marks around __file__ i.e. `"__file__"`

Comment: @cph2117: I'm not sure what you mean. I don't think powershell changes how `os.path.abspath` works.

Comment: It may not be a function of powershell, but when I tried without the quotations it threw an error saying that __file__ is not defined

Comment: @cph2117: this will only work if you run it in a script. There is no `__file__` if running from an interactive prompt. \

Comment: @BryanOakley that makes more sense given that the output was the root python directory :)

Comment: and to use both (works both as script and in the interactive python shell):
`try:`
    `path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`
`except Exception:`
     `path = os.getcwd()`
(with proper indentation)

Comment: `'__file__'` should work in both interactive prompts and basic running.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: have you actually tried it in an interactive prompt? `__file__` will not be set since there is no file. What do you think it would be set to?

Comment: @BryanOakley It was a string.

Comment: When I run ptyhon from emacs using `C-c, C-c`; `os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())` returns the parent base folder @Bryan Oakley

Comment: @alper: I'm not sure I understand your comment. `os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())` will always return the absolute path to the current working directory. It doesn't matter if you run it from emacs, IDLE, eclipse, or anything else.

Comment: When I run my code through script (`python run.py`) it returns its absolute path, but when I run inside `emacs` its returns the base folder, instead of the absolute path. Maybe I have current setup (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50194143/2402577) it may be the reason for it @Bryan Oakley

Comment: hmm...I'm getting "
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined"

Comment: @ScottyBlades did you see the last paragraph of the answer?

Comment: I’m running code from a file, not loading it.  What does interactively mean here?

Comment: ```pathlib.Path('__file__').parent.absolute()```

Comment: @Javi: you definitely shouldn't put `__file__` in quotes. That turns it from the filename of the current file to the literal 8-byte string `"__file__"`

Comment: Use the Path.resolve method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) instead of the Path.absolute method, which is undocumented.

Comment: to access the string name itself, use the as_posix() method, as: pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute().as_posix() and respectively pathlib.Path().absolute().as_posix()

Comment: @sorin does this still happen? If so, do you have any references?

Comment: @NikolaiEhrhardt: this works for me, are you saying it doesn't work for you? `python -c 'import os; print(os.path.abspath("/tmp"))'`

Comment: Don't forget that you can go to the parent directory without having to use the `.parent` method, you may concatenate: `__file__ + "/.."` (two dots indicate the parent directory).

Comment: What does `.resolve()` do? The output seems to be the same without it.

Comment: @CGFoX: here's the documentation for resolve: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve

Answer (score 199):

Using `Path` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is the recommended way since Python 3:

```
from pathlib import Path
print("File      Path:", Path(__file__).absolute())
print("Directory Path:", Path().absolute()) # Directory of current working directory, not __file__
```

**Note:** If using Jupyter Notebook, `__file__` doesn't return expected value, so `Path().absolute()` has to be used.

Comment: I had to do `Path(__file__).parent` to get the folder that is containing the file

Comment: That is correct @YellowPillow, `Path(__file__)` gets you the file.  `.parent` gets you one level above ie the containing directory.  You can add more `.parent` to that to go up as many directories as you require.

Comment: Sorry I should've have made this clearer, but if `Path().absolute()` exists in some module located at `path/to/module` and you're calling the module from some script located at `path/to/script` then would return `path/to/script` instead of `path/to/module`

Comment: @YellowPillow `Path(__file__).cwd()` is more explicit

Comment: `Path(__file__)` doesn't always work, for example, it doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook.  `Path().absolute()` solves that problem.

Comment: `Path(__file__)` worked in IDLE but when I used it in a python script that is executed from cmdline it would only return the name of script w/o its parents... strange...is there a bug? I had to use `Path(__file__).absolute()` as you had mentioned to reveal the full path. Occurred in python 3.6. Btw, I did not find the `.absolute()` method described in Python3.6 documentation.

Comment: Above comment was for a file. To get the file's parent directory, `Path().absolute()` and `Path(__file__).absolute().parent` gave the same result in Python3.6.

Comment: @SunBear what if you change the working directory to a different directory than the file?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner I don't quite understand your question. Suggest u post a question. If it helps, `Path.cwd()` always returns the current working directory.

Comment: for wiw;  `Path(__file__).absolute().parent` in the interactive terminal returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
` but specifically adding the file string seems to work.  Example: `Path('__file__').absolute().parent`  returns `PosixPath('/Users/.../.../foldername')`

Answer (score 109):

In Python 3.x I do:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
```

Explanation:

- `Path(__file__)` is the path to the current file.
- `.parent` gives you the *directory* the file is in.
- `.absolute()` gives you the *full absolute* path to it.

Using `pathlib` is the modern way to work with paths. If you need it as a string later for some reason, just do `str(path)`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2019. One thing could be mentioned in the answer as well: one can immediately call `.open()` on such a `Path` object as in `with Path(__file__).parent.joinpath('some_file.txt').open() as f:`

Comment: The other issue with some of the answers (like the one from Ron Kalian, if I'm not mistaken), is that it will give you the current directory, not necessarily the __file__ path.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: Best answer. This is the way I usually get the current script path, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

```py
import os
print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Sorry but this answer is incorrect, the correct one is the one made by Bryan `dirname(abspath(__file__)). See comments for details.

Comment: It will give `/ ` as output

Comment: @sorin Actually on Python 3.6 they are both the same

Answer (score 7):

I found the following commands return the full path of the parent directory of a Python 3 script.

**Python 3 Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pathlib import Path

#Get the absolute path of a Python3.6 and above script.
dir1 = Path().resolve()  #Make the path absolute, resolving any symlinks.
dir2 = Path().absolute() #See @RonKalian answer 
dir3 = Path(__file__).parent.absolute() #See @Arminius answer
dir4 = Path(__file__).parent 

print(f'dir1={dir1}\ndir2={dir2}\ndir3={dir3}\ndir4={dir4}')
```

**REMARKS !!!!**

1. `dir1` and `dir2` works only when running a script located in the current working directory, but will break in any other case.
2. Given that `Path(__file__).is_absolute()` is `True`, the use of the `.absolute()` method in dir3 appears redundant.
3. **The shortest command that works is dir4**.

Explanation links: [.resolve()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.Path.resolve), [.absolute()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098973/5722359), [Path(**file**).parent().absolute()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892023/5722359)

Comment: A bare ``Path()`` does *not* provide the script/module directory. It is equivalent to ``Path('.')`` – the *current working* directory.  This is equivalent only when running a script located in the current working directory, but will break in any other case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have updated your comment to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

USEFUL PATH PROPERTIES IN PYTHON:

```py
from pathlib import Path

#Returns the path of the current directory
mypath = Path().absolute()
print('Absolute path : {}'.format(mypath))

#if you want to go to any other file inside the subdirectories of the directory path got from above method
filePath = mypath/'data'/'fuel_econ.csv'
print('File path : {}'.format(filePath))

#To check if file present in that directory or Not
isfileExist = filePath.exists()
print('isfileExist : {}'.format(isfileExist))

#To check if the path is a directory or a File
isadirectory = filePath.is_dir()
print('isadirectory : {}'.format(isadirectory))

#To get the extension of the file
fileExtension = mypath/'data'/'fuel_econ.csv'
print('File extension : {}'.format(filePath.suffix))
```

**OUTPUT:**
ABSOLUTE PATH IS THE PATH WHERE YOUR PYTHON FILE IS PLACED

Absolute path : `D:\Study\Machine Learning\Jupitor Notebook\JupytorNotebookTest2\Udacity_Scripts\Matplotlib` and `seaborn Part2`

File path : `D:\Study\Machine Learning\Jupitor Notebook\JupytorNotebookTest2\Udacity_Scripts\Matplotlib` and `seaborn Part2\data\fuel_econ.csv`

isfileExist : True

isadirectory : False

File extension : .csv

Comment: Thx. Works also perfect in JupyterLab

Comment: this is misleading absolute is cwd not where your file is placed. not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: ``Path()`` is the current working directory, not the directory of the script. This only "works" in the few cases where the script actually is in the current working directory.

Answer (score 5):

## for `jupyter notebooks`

In `jupyter notebooks` the `__file__` variable is not available. However, the kernels `working directory` is equal to the notebooks location. Hence you can use

option 1

```
%cwd
```

option 2

```
from pathlib import Path
Path.cwd()
```

option 3

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
path_file = Path(sys.path[0])
print(path_file)
```

This works if you called your notebook

- by `jupyter notebook` and navigated manually to your notebook
- directly by `jupyter notebook tmp2/Untitled.ipynb`

**Info**: Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), is the object oriented (and recommended) way of handling paths in python 3.

Thanks for @bjmc for your comment, pointing out that this solution was actually accessing the working directory.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `sys.path[0]` contains the current working directory for the python interpreter, not the directory where the Python source code file exists. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: @bjmc yes and no. It works in jupyter notebooks, as the kernels working directory is equal to the notebooks directory. However this answer seems to help people, so I will modify it ...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 and 3

You can simply also do:

```py
from os import sep
print(__file__.rsplit(sep, 1)[0] + sep)
```

Which outputs something like:

```
C:\my_folder\sub_folder\
```

Comment: On a `windows 7` machine with `python3.8.10` that I just tested it , for some reason `__file__` doesn't seem to return any path but only just the file-name. Just saying in case anyone else ...

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a module.

```
def get_path():
    return (__file__.replace(f"<your script name>.py", ""))
print(get_path())
```

Answer (score 0):

`IPython` has a magic command `%pwd` to get the present working directory. It can be used in following way:

```
from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed

ip_shell = InteractiveShellEmbed()

present_working_directory = ip_shell.magic("%pwd")
```

On IPython Jupyter Notebook `%pwd` can be used directly as following:

```
present_working_directory = %pwd
```

Comment: The question isn't about IPython

Comment: @Kiro, my solution *answers the question* using IPython. For example If some one answers a question with a solution using a new library then also imho it remains a pertinent answer to the question.

Comment: @NafeezQuraishi your solution introduces a third party library, and a class from which you have to instantiate in order to achieve the desired result. Myself, and I think many others try to avoid using external libraries for a number of reasons, and I would only try your solution if nothing else worked. Luckily, there's a series of built in functions you can use to get the desired result, and without the need of an external library.

Comment: @elli0t, partially agree. Consider someone using Jupyter notebook has this question for whom perhaps using %pwd magic command would be easier and preferable over os import.

Comment: The question isn't about getting the present working directory, it's about getting the directory of the script. Those two can be very different things.

Comment: current file in question indicates current/present working dir

Comment: @NafeezQuraishi: I don't know what you mean. The question is clearly asking about the path to the directory that the file is in, which may not be the current working directory. Those are two different concepts.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Ahh, i see. Yes agree these can be two different things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function to use when running python under IIS in CGI in order to get the current folder:

```
import os 
def getLocalFolder():
    path=str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))).split(os.sep)
    return path[len(path)-1]
```