# What is a frozen Python module?

Tags: python, module, imp

The Python help of the module `imp` is talking about a frozen module. What is it?

http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.PY_FROZEN

Comment: You realize that it points to an explanation right there in that doc? Were you looking for a detailed answer about what the Freeze process is?

Comment: Yeah, you're right I was looking for the freeze process. I read the part. I will reformat it or create a new question.

Comment: No problem. I just posted an answer to that then.

Comment: write it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916647/what-is-the-python-freeze-process
I will close this question.

Comment: `import __hello__`

Comment: what is alternative in python 3.7

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This link explains what the Python Freeze utility is in detail:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

In a nutshell, it creates a portable version of a python script that carries its own built in interpreter (basically like a binary executable), so that you can run it on machines without python.

Answer (score 9):

http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.PY_FROZEN links to http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen which explains it:

> Frozen modules are modules written in Python whose compiled byte-code object is incorporated into a custom-built Python interpreter by Python’s freeze utility. See Tools/freeze/ for now.

Comment: Also by utility py2exe

Comment: The above quoted text is now at https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen - but I can't find that description, or anything similar, in the Python 3.x documentation. It may be there, I just haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the [same place](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen):

> (Frozen modules are modules written in Python whose compiled byte-code object is incorporated into a custom-built Python interpreter by Python’s freeze utility. See Tools/freeze/ for now.)