# What is the Python freeze process?

Tags: python, freeze

The Python Doc states:

> Frozen modules are modules written in Python whose compiled byte-code
>   object is incorporated into a custom-built Python interpreter by
>   Python’s freeze utility. See Tools/freeze/ for now.

http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen

I don't get it. What is the freeze utility? How can it be used? Why would it be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link explains what the Python Freeze utility is in detail: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

In a nutshell, it creates a portable version of a python script that carries its own built in interpreter (basically like a binary executable), so that you can run it on machines without python.

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to tools like py2exe: You can create a single executable that runs a python program without requiring the user to install separate packages, the python interpreter, etc.
It is only for Unix/Linux(/possibly OSX) systems though; on Windows you use py2exe for it.

Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze for more information.

Comment: Oh you bastard. That was my answer from the other question and the OP told me to post it over here :-P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916432/what-is-a-frozen-python-module#comment12655698_9916432

Comment: Username checks out