# Difference between Python frozen and built-in modules

Tags: python, module

What is the difference between Python's frozen and built-in modules?

UPD: I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916432/what-is-a-frozen-python-module), but then what is built-in module?

Comment: Sorry, what is frozen?

Comment: [Look here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html). There are a few words about importing frozen modules, and built-in modules, but I do not understand what it is exactly.