# How does "import __hello__" work?

Tags: python, import, module

Recently I've come across this "Hello world" Python program:

```
>>> import __hello__
Hello world!
```

I wonder how it works and how to view the source code of the  `__hello__` module.

Comment: For Python 3.11, add `__hello__.main()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__hello__` is a [frozen module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916432/what-is-a-frozen-python-module) intended as a test case for frozen module support. Its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/frozen.c) is automatically generated by the Python freeze utility.

Comment: The source can be found here for cpython: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/freeze/hello.py

Comment: @NickA: It sure looks that way at first glance, but that's actually the wrong file. Note the difference in punctuation.

Comment: (Or at least, it's the wrong file on Python 3. They changed it, I think in [issue 11614](http://bugs.python.org/issue11614).)

Comment: @user2357112 no kidding..., importing it in python 2.7 indeed has the ellipsis while python 3.4 has !

Comment: @NickA: it's the [`Tools/freeze/flag.py` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/freeze/flag.py) that's frozen, not `hello.py`.