# Difference between a built-in, standard, and frozen module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between a Python module, a built-in module, a standard module, and a frozen module?

---

These terms come from the official documentation itself.

**Python module** and **built-in module** are mentioned in the [loader documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html#loaders):

> Loaders must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - If the module is a Python module (as opposed to a built-in module or a dynamically loaded extension), the loader should execute
>     the module’s code in the module’s global name space (module.__dict__).

**Standard module** is referenced in the [Top-Level Components documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/toplevel_components.html#index-2):

> all built-in and standard modules are available

**Frozen module** has [its own importer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.FrozenImporter), which is described as

> An importer for frozen modules

Despite mention in official documentation and core code, there is no definitive definition for Python module, builtin-module, standard module, or frozen module in the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html), [index](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex.html) ([B](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-B.html), [F](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-F.html), [M](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-M.html), [P](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-P.html), or [S](https://docs.python.org/3.6/genindex-S.html)), or (apparently) elsewhere.

---

#### Definition: Builtin-module

Here is the best definition I could come up with for builtin-module:

> A **builtin-module** is an [extension module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-extension-module) (i.e. written in C, Java, .NET, etc.) which
>   is listed in the `sys.builtin_module_names` attribute.  Note that this list may vary with the Python interpreter (i.e. a builtin-module for Cython may not be a builtin module for IronPython, etc.).

I pieced this definition together from the following sources:

The [documentation for the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html#the-python-standard-library) states,

> The library contains built-in modules (written in C)

The [`importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter) states,

> All known built-in modules are listed in `sys.builtin_module_names`.

The [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) attribute documentation in turn states,

> the names of all modules that are compiled into this Python
>   interpreter. (This information is not available in any other way)

---

#### Definition: frozen module*

The Python2.7 [`imp` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen) states,

> A **frozen module** is a module written in Python whose compiled
>   byte-code object is incorporated into a custom-built Python
>   interpreter by Python’s freeze utility.

It's worth noting that this definition is not present in the Python3 docs. Whether this omission is an oversight is unclear.  Reference is still made in the Python3 docs to frozen modules.

---

I have not had any luck finding resources that help define Python module or standard module.

* Thanks to @martineau for the reference

Comment: This may partially help [What is a frozen Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916432/what-is-a-frozen-python-module) Also, a built-in module is kind of the opposite of an extension module, so saying the former _is_ the latter is self-contradictory.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on the contradiction?  The official documentation, as far as I can tell, implies that a builtin-module is an extension module, via the parenthetical remark "(written in C)".  By the linked definition, an extension module must be 1) written in C and 2) use Python’s C API to interact with the core and with user code.  Builtin-modules, as I've defined them, satisfy both criteria (unless they don't utilize the C API).  https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-extension-module

Comment: Sure, it's simple: An extension module is one written by a third-party that extends the interpreter's capabilities, whereas as a built-in one is comes with it.

Comment: At risk of being pedantic, the following seems to imply otherwise, that a builtin-module can be an extension.  It also implies that builtin-modules aren't necessarily part of the Python core (which, although not part of my definition, is a confusing way to interpret "built-in").  It states, "It is quite easy to add new built-in modules to Python, if you know how to program in C. Such extension modules..."  Maybe the doc means to say "It is quite easy to add new built-in modules (via an approved pull request into the Python core)..."?  https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain in simple language to make one understand easily. Modules are nothing but python files(with .py extension) containing collection of functions.(Not just function, Sometimes class and functions). Anybody can create module. For instance,imagine as if you are creating 4 functions viz., add, subtract,multiply and divide in a single python file and you are naming the python file as arithmetic (as follows)

```
# arithmetic.py
def add(a,b): return a+b
def subtract(a,b): return a-b
def multiply(a,b): return a*b
def divide(a,b): return a/b
```

Now the file name arithmetic is your module name. Now let us consider if you are creating another python file namely 'add.py' **within the same directory** . In case if this python file needs to perform addition operation, then you can import add function from your arithmetic module as follows:

```
#add.py
from arithmetic import add
r = add(5, 6)
print(r) # output 11
```

In this way you can create as many modules as you want and you can import and call the function in the later line of code. This simplifies the process.

In pypi.org, modules(or libraries) published by plenty of programmers worldwide is readily available. According to the requirement, we can import and use these modules. Anybody can publish their module for which you have to follow the procedure given in the above website.

Built-in modules are part of the Python standard Library. That is it comes along with the python package and you can directly use it by importing them. You don't need to install these modules For eg., the modules like math, random, re etc., For using these in your code, you should mention import math / import random / import re etc., But these are not required to be installed.

External modules are additional third party modules are available added . If you want to use these modules, these need to be installed separately apart from your python package with the following code.

```
pip3 install <module-name>
```

Let us consider another environment say microcontroller like Arduino. Now a days programming inside the microcontroller can be done with python. (They call it micropython). But microcontrollers are very small chips and we should consider the memory usage. To reduce the memory usage, a process called freezing is done.  By the process of freezing, the code is compiled into a single file and the binary format is directly stored. The modules which undergo this freezing process are called frozen modules.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: "Built-in modules are the functions which need not even be imported" no, that isn't true.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for correcting me. I've edited now. Please go thru and let me know.

Comment: Is `freeze` part of `pip`?

Comment: @LoremIpsum, pip freeze is different from this freeze.  Here freezing is pre-processing of the modules

Comment: @LoremIpsum, There are freeze tools available which can be be installed with pip.

bbfreeze is one of such tools which can be installed with pip3 install bbfreeze

Answer (score -2):

Modules are files containing Python definitions and statements that can be used to organize and reuse code. They help in creating a modular and organized codebase.

- "Built-in modules" are modules that are automatically available in Python without the need for any external installation.

For example:

```
import os
```

- "Standard modules", also known as modules from the Python Standard Library, are modules that are part of the Python distribution and cover a wide range of functionalities. They can be considered as a subset of built-in modules in Python.

For example:

```
import os.path
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

- "Frozen modules" generally refers to modules that have been compiled into a binary format for efficient distribution or execution.

For example:

Let's say you have a python script called example_script.py

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile example_script.py
```

After running the above command, "pyinstaller" will create a "dist" directory, and inside it, you'll find the frozen executable for your script. The name of the executable will be the same as your script's name but without the .py extension.

This could be something like example_script.exe or simply example_script
It is a binary file that has already been compiled.

Now, you can run the frozen executable on your machine without requiring Python or any dependencies to be installed separately. The executable will work as a standalone application.

- "Python module" is simply a file containing Python code, saved with a .py extension.

Comment: "Module" is somewhat overloaded. It can be used to refer to the Python file, or the object *created by* executing the commands in a file. With that distinction in mind, build-in modules can be thought of as `module` objects defined directly in the interpreter, without going through the execute-a-series-of-Python-statements step.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).