# Using absolute_import and handling relative module name conflicts in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I really hope this is a simple case of me miss-understanding the complex Python2 import mechanisms. I have the following setup:

```
$> ls -ltr pypackage1 
total 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 pelson pelson   0 Aug 17 19:20 io.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pelson pelson   0 Aug 17 19:20 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pelson pelson  57 Aug 17 19:22 code.py
$> cat pypackage1/code.py 
from __future__ import absolute_import

import zipfile
```

i.e. I have nothing but a stub package with an empty `__init__.py` and `io.py`, and a 2 lines `code.py` file.

I can import `pypackage1`:

```
$> python -c "import pypackage1.code"
```

But I cannot run the `code.py` file:

```
$> python pypackage1/code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pypackage1/code.py", line 3, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "python2.7/zipfile.py", line 462, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

Clearly the problem has to do with the `zipfile` module picking up my relative io module over the builtin `io` module, but I thought my `from __future__ import absolute_import` would have fixed that.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: Is it not possible to rename the `io.py` to e.g `__io.py`

Comment: Why does `zipfile.py` appear to be in a local directory?

Comment: I tried to replicate this. If I run it from *outside* the package directory, it worked without raising any errors.  From within the package directory, it raises the same `BufferedIOBase` error that you mention. This is a weird problem, but is it really going to be an issue for you in practice? (particularly if you use the normal Python package structure)

Comment: @JeffTratner that is how (relative) imports have always worked in Python.  The current directory is automatically part of `sys.path`.

Comment: @Kimvais: Of course I *could*, but thats not a very nice solution (and I won't learn something new that way). :-)

Comment: @ecatmur: That was just me copying and pasting as much as was necessary. I don't have any fruity python setup going on just in case you are wondering.

Comment: @JeffTratner: The reason I am asking this question is because it was a problem for me in practice. I have a "tests.py" module which was runnable, but was getting these namespacing issues. Sounds like the proper solution is to not directly invoke subpackage modules, instead wrapping them outside of the package.

Comment: @pelson, I guess I usually avoid this issue by putting the tests and the package files each in separate directories and then running the test from the base directory.

Comment: Actually, _not_ using overlapping names with standard library packages and builtins _is_ a nice solution, in my opinion.

Comment: .. And, since we're talking about collisions with stdlib names, how about ***not*** using `code` as a module name? Afterall, there *is* a `code` module in standard lib ;)

Comment: The point is, its my namespace (I'm not talking about defining top level packages of these names), so I can put whatever I want in there. Be it ``code``, ``io`` or anything else. @Bakuriu's answer was the correct solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the correct behaviour. If you want to fix the error simply do not run from inside the package.

When you run a script which is inside the package, python wont interpret that directory as a package, thus adding the working directory to the `PYTHONPATH`.
That's why the `io` module imported by the `zipfile` module is your `io` module and not the one inside the standard library.

I'd recommend to create a simple launcher script outside your package (or in a `bin/scripts` folder), and launch that. This script can simply contain something like:

```
from pypackage1 import code

code.main()
```

---

An alternative to this is to tell the python interpreter that the file that you want to execute is part of a module. You can do this using the `-m` command line option. In your case you would have to do:

```
python -m pypackage1.code
```

Note that the argument of `-m` should be the *module name*, not the file name.

Comment: "When you run a script which is inside the package, python wont interpret that directory as a package, thus adding the working directory to the [`sys.path`]." However, by default, it **will** add the current working directory to the front of `sys.path`. If this folder contains its own `io.py`, therefore, the problem re-emerges. This can be addressed using command-line switches and/or the `PYTHONSAFEPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put `from __future__ import absolute_import` in the `zipfile.py` module.  Although *your* module is using absolute import, the *zipfile* module is not.

Another option is to not run from your package directory.  You probably shouldn't be running the interpreter from within the package directory.

Comment: Yes, I think this would work. Sadly, zipfile is the python stock zipfile module and I have no desire to modify the code (nor do I actually have the permissions to either). One of the reasons I am asking this question is because I am curious as to why the standard python library doesn't use ``from __future__ import absolute_import``.

Comment: I agree that modifying the standard library isn't recommended practice.  I suspect that the standard library doesn't use the future-import because changing it is unnecessary: it already works the way it has always worked.  If the future imports were added, then they should subsequently be removed when the new behavior becomes standard.

Comment: Aside from the issue with modifying standard library files, this **wouldn't fix the problem**. The problem occurs because, with absolute import **already enabled** by the `__future__` import, the attempt to `import io` searches `sys.path`, and finds the project's code before other standard library code.

Answer (score 1):

File structure:

```
test.py
mylib/__init__.py
mylib/__collections.py
mylib/collections.py
mylib/mymod.py
```

This solution allows for:

- test.py to invoke both __builtin__.collections and mylib.collections
- mymod.py to invoke the above, both when it runs as part of the library *and* when it is run standalone (e.g. for test code)

In test.py:

```
from collections import deque
from mylib.collections import mydict
```

In mylib/__init__.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import collections
from . import mymod
```

In mylib/__collections.py:

```
class MyDict (dict):
    pass
```

In mylib/collections.py:

```
from __collections import *
```

In mylib/mymod.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from collections import deque
try:
    # Module running as part of mylib
    from .collections import MyDict
except ValueError:
    # Module running independently
    from __collections import MyDict
```

The above works with Python >=2.5. Python 3 doesn't need the lines 'from __future__ import absolute_import'.