# Refer to stdlib module from inside a module of the same name

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

I've named a module `blah.tty` within a project of mine. Now I have a need to access the stdlib top-level `tty` module from inside it. Is this possible without doing magic tricks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using absolute\_import and handling relative module name confilcts in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011327/using-absolute-import-and-handling-relative-module-name-confilcts-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute imports:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Now `import tty` will refer to the top-level stdlib module. Refer to package-relative names either by using the full path (`import blah.tty`) or use dots to demark relative paths (`from . import tty`, etc.) See [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: Thanks! Why is the `__future__` package named as such, out of curiosity?

Comment: @d11wtq: because it is not a module, really. It is a hint to the parser instead. Well, it is *is* a module, to avoid confusing tools that'll look for that module, but its purpose is still to set parser options.

Comment: @d11wtq: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future and https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html for more info.