# How to import standard library module instead of local directory?

Tags: python

I have a local directory named "calendar" with an "__init__.py" file.

I want "import calendar" to import the standard library module calendar, and not the module defined by my local directory.

I already tried "from __future__ import absolute_import" and changing PYTHONPATH.

There are Good Reasons I can't just rename the directory. Really.

Comment: You can `import sys` and rearrange `sys.path` yourself.  However, if you're saying you actually have a directory on `sys.path` that has a package/module named the same as a builtin one (i.e., your `calendar` is at the top level on the path), you really need to rename it (there are even better reasons, really).  There's no general way to resolve top-level name conflicts.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the current working directory (as either `''` or `'.'`, depending on version/platform) is always at the top of `sys.path` when you start up Python.

Using absolute imports makes no difference—that just means to look in `sys.path` first, instead of looking for relative imports before falling back to `sys.path`.

The right solution is obviously to either (a) rename `calendar`, or (b) move it into subpackage of some other package instead of having it at the top level. Whatever your Good Reasons are, the Good Reasons for doing the right thing are likely even better.

---

But if you must get around this, there are a few things you can do. The simplest is to temporarily munge `sys.path`:

```
syspath = sys.path
sys.path = [path for path in sys.path if path.strip('.')]
import calendar
sys.path = syspath
```

---

However, no matter what you do, this is going to cause *huge* problems. When you later try to import your local package `calendar`—even if you're doing so from a completely different source file—nothing will happen, because there's already something named `calendar` in `sys.modules`, so that other source file will just get the stdlib `calendar` module instead of your package.

So you'll also need to rename one or the other on the fly and remove it from `sys.modules`. Maybe this:

```
syspath = sys.path
sys.path = [path for path in sys.path if path.strip('.')]
calmod = sys.modules.get('calendar')
del sys.modules['calendar']
calendar = __import__('calendar')
sys.modules['calendar'] = calmod
sys.path = syspath
```

And, depending on the order at which your modules get run (which may not be easily predictable, or even deterministic), there's a good chance you'll need similar hackery in the other location.

(What if you never actually need to import your local package `calendar`? Well, in that case you don't have this problem… but then I can't imagine what your Good Reasons could possibly be…)

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed that there isn't an explicit way to say "import from the standard library", or even just modify PYTHONPATH to say "import from the place where I installed Python first".

Thanks for the details!

Comment: @JonathanPaulson: But you can't have two modules with the same qualified name—and that's global within your entire program—so such a language feature would just make it easier to accidentally trigger that ambiguity. If that isn't clear from the second half of my answer, my explanation probably sucks, so please let me know what you're not getting and I'll try again.

Comment: Now I am disappointed that the internal fully-qualified name for a module isn't prefixed with the element of sys.path it came from.

Comment: @JonathanPaulson: That would be a huge mess. The `sys.path` generally has your system-wide site-packages, your distro's dist-packages, your per-user site-packages, a directory for each `pip`-installed package, an eggfile for each `easy_install`-installed package, … And I can't see how it would help anything. If those names are internal only, there's no way to specify which of the two you wanted, so what's the use of having both? If they're accessible, then you'd end up having to write different code depending on whether, say, `bs4` was installed as a dist, sys-site, user-site, etc. package…

Comment: @JonathanPaulson: There _was_ a proposal for 3.0 to get rid of all built-in top-level packages and move everything into one giant `std` package (much as C++98 moved the whole stdlib into a `std::` namespace), which would have solved this problem… but if you can't imagine all the reasons people wouldn't want that, you can search for the long argument threads…

Comment: How does Python make e.g. sure that standard library modules that import other standard library modules, really use those, and not just a local one?
Imagine one imports `pathlib` (from the standard library), which in turn does `import os` (i.e. no relative import). If now locally there is a `os.py`, that would be taken. If you say just don't use those names, fine, but what if new ones are later added to the standard lib?

Answer (score 3):

You could modify [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), import the package, then restore `sys.path` to its original value.

```
import sys
original_path = sys.path
sys.path = original_path[1:]
import calendar
sys.path = original_path
```

Answer (score 2):

As the rest says, the best option is to rename the calendar module into a new module not used by standard library.

But as a workaround if that's not possible, you could create a another module (visible in the syspath) outside the directory where the local `calendar.py` file is placed.

So if you have a hierarchy like this:

```
project/
   __init__.py
   app1/
      __init__.py
      calendar.py
      module_in_which_i_want_to_use_python_std_calendar.py
```

You could create a new module named `std_calendar.py` outside apps (outside calendar.py is placed). In this file you could import calendar (this will be standard calendar module)

```
from calendar import *
```

And the hierarchy would be:

```
project/
   __init__.py
   std_calendar.py
   app1/
      __init__.py
      calendar.py
      module_in_which_i_want_to_use_python_std_calendar.py
```

In `module_in_which_i_want_to_use_python_std_calendar.py` you could use standard calendar with:

```
from project import std_calendar as calendar
```