# Import with files names conflict

Tags: python, import, serial-port

I'm trying to develop a simulation class that replaces `serial` at specific apps(Win7, python 2.7).

I have a `SerialHandle` class that works in number of apps, It's job is add logic to the well known serial methods, the idea was to replace python `serial.py` with a dummy file with the same name so we won't have to change and imports at `SerialHandle`.

Now i have this file with `Serial` class just like the origin and it works fine:

```
serial.py
...Serial()
```

Since i want to really simulate the methods i need the `SerialException` from `serialutil`
so inside my serial.py i'm trying to import it using:

`from serial import SerialException`

But as expected i'll get this raise since `from serial` goes to the local file at first:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/CROW/ATE/DUTDrivers/DD_SimulatorExample/DD_SimulatorExample.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Utilities.Serial.SerialHandle.trunk.SerialHandle import SerialHandle
  File "C:\CROW\ATE\Utilities\Serial\SerialHandle\trunk\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Utilities.Simulator import serial
  File "C:\CROW\ATE\Utilities\Simulator\serial.py", line 11, in <module>
    from serial import SerialException
ImportError: cannot import name SerialException
```

I understand the problem is the file name since at any other file it will work...

I've tried `sys.append(site-packages....serial.py)` no luck.

**Questions:**

1. Any way to tell the interpreter to ignore the local file at a specific from..import?
2. Is there any other way to import from an absolute path?

**Notes:**

1. the file naming as `serial.py` is not a decision it's a definition so changing the name is not relevant...
2. Overloading python serial is not an option also...

Comment: What about copying SerialException from python source code and paste it into your module?

Comment: @furins it will work for sure, the reason i asked this question is because i was wondering if there is some elegant solution...

Comment: then this approach should be what you are searching for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists?rq=1 (the approved answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be using python 2.x, since absolute imports are the default in python 3.x. You can use absolute imports in your *serial.py* file by adding this at the top of the file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Note that you will need to convert any implicit relative imports from your *serial.py* file into explicit relative imports. So if you were importing `some_func` from `other_file.py`, which is in the same directory, you would need to change that to:

```
from .other_file import some_func
```

Note that the "." indicates a relative import from the same package as the current file. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for additional detail.

Comment: no, he needs the opposite. He need always to load implicitly from local sources except from inside his module.

Comment: That's what my answer explains. Importing `absolute_import` only affects the file in which it is used. Others would still use relative imports.

Comment: yes, but in the module he does not want to access the local file, he wants the python one.

Comment: And that is what my answer does. After importing `absolute_import`, when he then does `import serial`, it will import the top-level `serial` package (from the python distro).

Comment: actually both of you are right :) @furnis the link was very helpful! and with both the link and answer it solved the issue!, thanks.