# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextCalendar'

Tags: python, calendar

When I copy the below code in Ideone then it runs fine but it is not running in the text editor and showing the error mentioned in the subject of this post:

```
import calendar   
c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
c.prmonth(2007, 7)
```

The complete error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calendar   
  File "/home/shl/Desktop/calendar.py", line 2, in <module>
    c = calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextCalendar'
```

Comment: Cannot re produce, python 2.7, please add your entire traceback and code.

Comment: You named your script `calendar.py`, didn't you? Next time, show a whole traceback. (Also, I have no idea what "running in the text editor" means.)

Answer (score 8):

change the program name from calendar.py to something like calendar_code.py

This wold work properly.

[Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)