# How to deal with name conflict between standard library and third library in Python?

Tags: python, import

Suppose I have developed a third library named `foo` first, and then a new standard library also named `foo` is added into Python. Can I still use my version of `foo` without bothering to change its name?

Any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists

Comment: Thank you! But `foo` is a third library (need to be installed), not a module, any suggestions with this situation?

Comment: You should rename your module, so that 1. You and anyone else using it doesn't have to jump through hoops to do so and 2. You can use the (presumably related!) functionality that Python is providing.

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I think the import mechanism of Python, in which all libraries are located in one namespace, is not good enough. Thank you anyway!