# python import package globally

Tags: python, python-2.7

### My directory structure is:

```
package_name/
  __init__.py
  script.py
  time.py
```

I'm trying to import `time` **(the built-in package)** from `script.py`. however, my sibling `time.py` is hooked up instead.

**What's the syntax of importing a package *globally*?** (e.g. importing from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`)

- In `c#` i know it as the `global::` prefix, what's the equivalent in python?

Comment: There isn't one, rename your script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/python-importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A Hack

While there are other ways, i adopted this one

**1) add a sub package**

Let's call it **`utils`**. your directory tree should look like:

```
package_name/
  __init__.py
  script.py
  time.py

  utils/
      __init__.py
```

**2) create a file named `builtin.py` under that package**

This should be the contents of `builtin.py` :

```
import time
time = time
```

**3) use it!**

Import `time` in `script.py` using this:

```
from utils.builtin import time

time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be more explicit with your imports.
`import time` will import the python time module.
`from mypackage import time` will import the time module in your mypackage package.

`import time` should never import mypackage.time

That said, don't shadow python built-in names, it's a bad habit and leads to these headaches later.

Comment: That's frustrating advice when python adds features that shadow names we already have