# Release application tests as a Python module

Tags: python, module, package, setuptools, setup.py

I'd like to have my tests on a module of its own that could be imported, but keeping them outside the `src` folder and at the same time sharing the namespace with the application module (something like `my-module.test.unit`) Is it even possible? Am I complicating it too much?

Directory structure:

```
root/
    src/
        my-module/
    test/
        end-to-end/
        unit/
            helper.py
            test_foo.py
    setup.py
```

setup.py

```
setup(
    # ...
    'packages'=['my-module'],
    'package_dir'={'': 'src'}
    # ...
)
```

Possible options I've figured:

- [Python's Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/)
- Change setup.py:

  ```
  setup(
      # ...
      'packages'=['my-module', 'my-module.test.unit'],
      'package_dir'={
          'my-module': 'src', # doesn't work in editable mode
          'my-module.test.unit': 'test/unit'
      }
      # ...
  )
  ```
- Create another setup.py inside the `test` folder

The rationale is that I have some helper modules in the same folder than the tests (e.g. `test/unit/helper.py`) and they are imported using absolute imports (e.g. `from helper import Helper`). There's nothing necessarily wrong in this setup because it works, but *hypothetically* a new built-in module could shadow any of mine because they take precedence. I believe that relative imports are better because there is no room left for interpretations (`explicit is better than implicit`). AFAIK, if my tests were a package by themselves I could bring that modules using relative imports (e.g. `from .helper import Helper`).

In the end it's more a matter of good practices and correctness than a real issue and because of that `practicality beats purity` also applies ;)

References on this:

- [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists/8280677#8280677)
- [PEP 0328 - Rationale for Relative Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports)

Comment: What exactly is your motivation for keeping the tests separate? If it's testing-only dependencies that you for example don't want to install when deploying in production, consider using a `[tests`] [extra](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). You would then only pull in those dependencies if you install your package with something like `pip install mymodule[tests]`. ([example](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.tika/blob/a2868b3a7bcf30ab2187413776810e2e486a2cee/setup.py#L60-L61))

Comment: @LukasGraf I added an explanation of the reasons. I will give a try at the `extras_require` option.