# How to create custom module with existing python module name and import that system module in the custom module

Tags: python

For example:
shutil is default python module

I have created custom python file called shutil.py and below is the code in that shutil.py file

```
import shutil
shutil.move('test.py', 'test/test.py')
```

It returned below error instead of calling python shutil module which was imported in this shutil.py file

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'move'
```

Please help me in this

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rename the import with `as` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your line down like so:

```
import shutil 
shutil.move('test.py', 'test/test.py')
```